# Choosing the largest dowry (or secretary problem)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) presented on a different form in the Problem 47 of "Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions"

> The king to test a candidate for the position of wise man, offers him a chance to marry the young lady in the court with the largest dowry. The amounts of the dowries are written on slips of paper and mixed. A slip is drawn at random and the wise man must decide whether that is the largest dowry or not. If he decides it is, he gets the lady and her dowry if he is correct; otherwise he gets nothing. If he decides against the amount written on the first slip, he must choose or refuse the next slip, and so until he chooses one or else the slips are exhausted. In all, 100 attractive young ladies participate, each with a different dowry. How should the wise man make his decision?

In the solutions, the author says

> Let the king draw the slips and report to the wise man only the rank of a slip among those drawn thus far. Only a slip that has the largest dowry thus far is with considering; call such a dowry a *candidate*.

This is correct and I don't have any doubt so far. Later on, there is a sentence that I don't understand

> The probability at draw $i$ of a candidate's being the largest in the entire sample is the probability that the maximum is among the first $i$ draws, namely $i/n$

where $n$ is the size of the sample. In our case $n=100$.

Is this last statement true? I don't understand why the probability of a candidate $i$ to be the largest value of the sample is the probability that the maximum is among the first $i$ draws. Indeed, if the maximum appears among the first $i$ draws, $i$ cannot be a candidate.

Comment: The maximum can be any of the $n$, uniformly. The probability that it appears in any given subset of size $i$ is $\frac in$

Comment: Note it is an assumption of the process that draw $i$ is at least the largest of the first $i$. That's how a candidate is defined.

Comment: Is that a book?

Answer (score 1):

Even I was confused on this line in the book for long time.
One way to see it is to write everything formally.
A : $ i^{th}$ dowry is largest among the ${1,2,...i}$ dowries offered.
B : Overall largest dowry is offered at $i^{th}$ position.
we are interested in $P(\frac{B}{A})$
$P(\frac{B}{A}) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(\frac{A}{B})*P(B)}{P(A)}$
Now it is easy to see $P(\frac{A}{B}) = 1, P(B) = \frac{1}{n}$
For $P(A)$, any of the numbers from $(1,..,i)$ can be largest so the probability that largest is at $i_{th}$ position is $P(A) = \frac{1}{i}$.
So $P(\frac{B}{A}) = \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{i}} = \frac{i}{n}$.